# Marshal an attribute in single quotes instead of double possible?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using JAXB to marshal an entity of mine into this:

```
<User id="blabla">asd,123</User>
```

On the receiving end there is some legacy code that doesn't accept xml attributes with double quotes, just single quotes. So it can't parse my xml.

Is it possible to marshal my entity into this:

```
<User id='blabla'>asd,123</User>
```

where the attribute `id` is wrapped with single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: I don't think so, unless there are implementation-specific options. You may have to capture the XML to a string buffer and manually swap the quotes. A legacy parser that can't handle double-quoted attributes is *not* an XML parser, it's just vaguely similar to one, so you're going to have to jump through hoops to make JAXB's output fit its requirements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I print single quotes around attribute values instead of double quotes with the javax.xml.transform.Tansformer class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186214/how-can-i-print-single-quotes-around-attribute-values-instead-of-double-quotes-w)

Comment: Maybe it's not really a duplicate but it supports @skaffman s comment. IMO you should modify the legacy system so that it understands well-formated XML. I know this is not always easy/possible, but circumventing old bugs by creating invalid (unparsable) XML documents is IMO the worst thing you can do.

Comment: The legacy code is being fixed. The legacy app is a client side app and it will take quite a while until everyone who uses it will upgrade their app. The marshalling side is server side and it's preety easy to change its code base. So in the mean while it would be great if it was possible to marshal it with the single quotes so it would work and at a later time stop supporting this. I guess i'll try the method from the mentioned thread if there is no other idea...